# Finding feature extents (not layer extent) in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, extents

How can I find feature extents for each multipolygon in QGIS?

```
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
```

I want to calculate extents for each feature here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use a **virtual layer** from the data source manager.

```
select envelope(geometry) as geometry 
from mytable;
```

[image]

SpatiaLite API: http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-4.2.0.html

Comment: also a very smart solution

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use the field calculator and calculate the min and max values for the coordinates of each feature in a new column with: x_min($geometry) y_min($geometry) x_max($geometry) ... and so far

[image]

other way with python:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
for f in layer.getFeatures():
    print (f.geometry().boundingBox())
```

Comment: You can also use the `bounds()` function in the expression builder, eg to create geometries using the geometry by expression algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my final solution, based on the [answer by @eurojam](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/309587/115):

```
layer = processing.getObject(vector)
for f in layer.getFeatures():
    print (f.geometry().boundingBox().toString())
```